# How to put a restriction on the amount of dynamic element created by a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating dynamic links with `getPage()` from a list of `<option>` tag. It works great. The only problem is if the user select another option another link is created next to the previous one. I would like to tell `javascript` to delete one link if another link is created by user choice.

**html**

```
<!-- Dynamic Options -->
<select id="pages" onchange="getPage();">
<option><?=$selectpage;?></option></select>

<!-- Append dynamic link here -->
<div id="page_link"></div>
```

**javascript**

```
function getPage(){

//get select element
var e = document.getElementById("pages");

//get value of select option
var f = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value; 

//create link when user selects option   
var link = "nextpage.php?mylink=" + f;
var element = document.createElement("a");
var div = document.getElementById("page_link");
element.setAttribute("href", link);

//append classes to link
element.innerHTML = "Continue with selected option";
element.className += "btn ";
element.className += "btn-lg ";
element.className += "btn-default ";
element.className += "pull-right ";

//append link to div
div.appendChild(element);
}
```

Comment: Just before `div.appendChild(element)` put `div.innerHTML = '';`. This will clear the whole contents of the div before placing a new link element.

Comment: @PhaniKumarM: Thanks its working. Make your answer official and all the credits are yours. Cheers

Comment: If you only ever want 1 link, and the only thing changing is the href just change the href on that 1 link instead of creating a new one and deleting the old one

Comment: @BalloonFight Updated my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way is to clear the div innerHTML:

`div.innerHTML = '';`

As Patrick mentioned in his comments, if there is only one link and you want to update the link href attribute based on the selection, then you can use the below updated code:

```
function getPage() {
    //get select element
    var e = document.getElementById("pages");

    //get value of select option
    var f = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    //create link when user selects option   
    var link = "nextpage.php?mylink=" + f;
    var element;

    if (document.getElementById("a_link") == null) {
        element = document.createElement("a");
        element.id = "a_link"
    }
    else
        element = document.getElementById("a_link");

    var div = document.getElementById("page_link");
    element.setAttribute("href", link);

    //append classes to link
    element.innerHTML = "Continue with selected option";
    element.className += "btn ";
    element.className += "btn-lg ";
    element.className += "btn-default ";
    element.className += "pull-right ";

    //append link to div
    div.appendChild(element);
}
```